# Converting RSA signature to String

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, rsa, decoding

I'm creating my RSA Signature like this.

```
transactionStr = json.dumps(GenesisTransaction())
signature = rsa.sign(transactionStr.encode(), client.privateKey, 'SHA-1')
```

But I'm unable to get it to a string so I can save it.

I have tried decoding it using utf8

```
signature.decode("utf8")
```

but I get the error "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 2"
any way I can do this?
A RSA signature looks like this

```
b'aL\xe3\xf4\xbeEM\xc4\x9e\n\x9e\xf4M`\xba\x85*\x13\xd52x\xd9\\\xe8F\x1c\x07\x90[/\x9dy\xce\xa9IV\x89\xe0\xcd9\\_3\x1e\xaa\x80\xdea\xd1\xbem/\x8e\x91\xbd\x13\x12o\x8c\xed\xf6\x89\xb5\x0b'
```

Comment: Why don't you just keep it as `bytes`? Not all byte values are allowed in UTF-8, for instance '\xe3' is not, so `decode('utf-8')` will work sometimes but not always.

Comment: If you really want a (not so readable) `str` you may use `decode('latin-1')` anyhow

Comment: If you want to convert binary data (like the signature) into a string, you should use a [binary-to-text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) encoding, like Base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.decode('utf8')` is used to decode text encoded in UTF8, not arbitrary bytes. Convert the byte string to a hexadecimal string instead:

```py
>>> sig = b'aL\xe3\xf4\xbeEM\xc4\x9e\n\x9e\xf4M`\xba\x85*\x13\xd52x\xd9\\\xe8F\x1c\x07\x90[/\x9dy\xce\xa9IV\x89\xe0\xcd9\\_3\x1e\xaa\x80\xdea\xd1\xbem/\x8e\x91\xbd\x13\x12o\x8c\xed\xf6\x89\xb5\x0b'
>>> s = sig.hex()
>>> s
'614ce3f4be454dc49e0a9ef44d60ba852a13d53278d95ce8461c07905b2f9d79cea9495689e0cd395c5f331eaa80de61d1be6d2f8e91bd13126f8cedf689b50b'
```

To convert back, if needed:

```py
>>> b = bytes.fromhex(s)
>>> b
b'aL\xe3\xf4\xbeEM\xc4\x9e\n\x9e\xf4M`\xba\x85*\x13\xd52x\xd9\\\xe8F\x1c\x07\x90[/\x9dy\xce\xa9IV\x89\xe0\xcd9\\_3\x1e\xaa\x80\xdea\xd1\xbem/\x8e\x91\xbd\x13\x12o\x8c\xed\xf6\x89\xb5\x0b'
>>> b==sig
True
```